# How to exclude the title tag from bs4 string searches with negated regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'd like to use bs4 to search for the first tag with a specific string and exclude the title tag from the search. According to the bs4 doc, it supports regular expressions.

Why doesn't the following code work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Dormouse's story</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
    <div class="title">The Dormouse's story</div>
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find(name=re.compile("^title"), string="The Dormouse's story")

if title is not None:
    print("String found:", title)
else:
    print("String not found.")

# returns: String found: <title>The Dormouse's story</title>
```

(I expected the code to find the `<b>The Dormouse's story</b>` tag.)

Does bs4/Python require a special regex syntax?

**Note:** I *do not* want alternative code suggestions. I want to know whether my code is faulty or whether bs4 doesn't support regular expressions contrary to what the documentation says.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter out 'titles' and match the string try this

```
def filter_out_titles(tag):
  return tag is not None and not tag.name == 'title'

soup.find_all(filter_out_titles, string="The Dormouse's story")
```

Comment: Thanks for you code! I'm pretty sure that it'd work, but I want to know why my code doesn't even though the bs4 doc mentions that it supports regular expressions for **find()**.

Comment: You need to add brackets otherwise it'll match string starting with "title"
    `soup.find_all(re.compile("[^title]"), string="The Dormouse's story")`

Answer (score 0):

```
title = soup.find(class_=re.compile(r"title"), string="The Dormouse's story")
```

The `class_` parameter will let you select by class names, what you were searching is by tag names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the actual tag that I'm looking for doesn't have unique class attributes or might not have any class attribute at all. (I just picked the default bs4 sample html code.)

Comment: have you tried something like `soup.findAll(text = re.compile('your regex here'))`?

Comment: `have you tried something like soup.findAll(text = re.compile('your regex here'))?` No, because I only need the first match.

Comment: soup.findAll(text = re.compile('your regex here'))[0]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the order of the printing statements to confirm that the script is looking for what you exactly want to parse from the HTML code, which is basically targeting this tag:

`<b>The Dormouse's story</b>`.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Dormouse's story</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
    <div class="title">The Dormouse's story</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find(class_=re.compile("^title"), string="The Dormouse's story")
print(title)

string = soup.find(str(title), 'html.parser')
final_string = soup.find('b')
print(final_string)

if final_string is not None:
    print("String found:", final_string)
else:
    print("String not found.")
```

Output:

```
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
<b>The Dormouse's story</b>
String found: <b>The Dormouse's story</b>
```